# Allow a person and his/hers friends to login and redirect to a page

Tags: facebook, facebook-authentication, facebook-login

I want to implement a login with facebook on my website. I have a client that log into the website and access a specific page, but I want all of client's friends could log into the website and see my client's page.

Is there a way to do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just retrieve the friend's list of the user and store them in database related to user. Then when a user login, check if this user is related to other users and redirect to the desired page.